# how to show the record side by side

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I am trying to show the record side by side . First row first column left side , second row first column right side   and so on . but not working please help
I am using the following model

```
public class Order()
{
   public string itemCode {get;set;}
   public string itemName {get;set;}
}

public class OrderList()
{
   public IEnumerable<Order> OrderList {get;set;}
}
```

```html
@model OrderList
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Order.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div style="display: inline-block">
                <div> @Model[i].ItemCode</div>
                <div> @Model[i].ItemName</div>
              
        }
        if (i% 3 == 2)
        {
        <br />
        }
```

In view

Comment: Can you upload more code? I'm guessing, but should: Model.Order.Count() be Model.OrderList.Count() and @Model[i].ItemCode should be @Model.OrderList[i].ItemCode?

Comment: But when I apply  @Model.OrderList[i].ItemCode the following error is showed in html. 'cannot appy indexing with [] to an expression type  IEnumerable<Order>

Comment: Can you try changing IEnumerable<Order> to List<Order>?

Comment: No I cannot change to List that cause another error in other places

Comment: If you want me to have a look into it, then upload some more code.

Comment: Thanks Greg thats working now. Many thanks